# iTextSharp: "The document is not open" error - when it actually is

Tags: itext

I have this code:

```
    private static byte[] ConvertPdfDocument(Document document, PdfPTable headerTable, PdfPTable affidavitsTable)
    {
        byte[] b;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

            if (document.IsOpen() == false)
            {
                document.Open();
            }

            document.Add(headerTable);
            document.Add(affidavitsTable);
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            b = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return b;
    }
```

The "document" object is opened (using `document.Open()` outside of this method then passed in.

The condition `document.IsOpen()` evaluates to True. I've further confirmed the document is actually open by looking at the private properties of the "document" object in the debugger; it shows that "Open" is "true".

Accordingly, execution moves on to the `document.Add(headerTable)` line.

And at that point an exception is thrown: "The document is not open."
And while the debugger is stopped (due to that exception being thrown), using the same two ways described above, I can **still** see the document is open.

How could that be?

I've been Googling for a while but can't find anything, other than the same question posted [here](http://www.tagwith.com/question_1458483_itextsharp-the-document-is-not-open-but-it-is-open) with no answer...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much,
Eliezer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The document must be opened after being used in `PdfWriter.GetInstance()` otherwise there no writer associated and it does nothing.

Comment: Paulo, you are correct; opening the document "again" (e.g. document.Open();) does work. But why does the IsOpen() method return True when it's apparently not the case?...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.  The IsOpen() method returns "true" and then the Close() method throws an exception stating the document isn't open.

Answer (score 0):

create document out of the for loop

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\addLife271118\\src\\assets\\finalbill.pdf"));
document.open();

try {       
    document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    String[] names= {"james","siva"};

    for(int i= 0; i< names.length;i++)
    {
      document.add(new Paragraph(names[i]));
      document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    }   
} catch (DocumentException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

document.close();
```