# C# iTextSharp How to convert a piece of HTML into PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF page that contains recipient address, subject, content and disclaimer. I have a problem with the disclaimer part because it is derived from another table and contains string of html.

How do I convert the disclaimer part and add this to the existing PDF page that is currently opened? I tried below method but I got an error that said 'The document is not open.'. Please help.

Example of disclaimer string:

```
string disclaimerStr = "<p>Disclaimer ....</p><p></p><p>The contents of page, are provided "as is" and "as available" basis without warranties of any kind either expressed or implied made in relation to the correctness, accuracy, timeliness or reliability of the content. Content provided in this website is for general information only and cannot be seen as an invitation to invest into the products and services mentioned.</p>"


Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 35, 25);
Font titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, Font.BOLD);
Font subTitleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14, Font.BOLD);
Font boldTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD);
Font endingMessageFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.ITALIC);
Font bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string fundList = "", emailContent = "", holderList = "";

        if (Request.QueryString["fl"] != null)
        {
            fundList = new QueryStringEncryption().Decrypt(Request.QueryString["fl"].Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            fundList = Session["fl"].ToString().Trim();
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["hl"] != null)
        {
            holderList = new QueryStringEncryption().Decrypt(Request.QueryString["hl"].Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            holderList = Session["hl"].ToString().Trim();
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["ec"] != null)
        {
            emailContent = new QueryStringEncryption().Decrypt(Request.QueryString["ec"].Trim());
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["ls"] != null)
        {
            letterSubject = Request.QueryString["ls"].Trim();
        }

        CreatePdf(fundList, emailContent, holderList);
    }
}

private void CreatePdf(string fundCodeList, string emailContent, string holderList)
{
    try
    {
        // Add ' to each holder in string
        var sHolderList = string.Join(",", holderList.Split(',').Select(w => string.Format("'{0}'", w)));

        // Create a new PdfWrite object, writing the output to a MemoryStream
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

        // Open the Document for writing
        document.Open();

        DataSet ds = new AccountHolder().GetHolderParticulars(Cs, null, sHolderList);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            document.NewPage();

            holderAddress = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TITLE"].ToString()))
            {
                holderAddress = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TITLE"].ToString().Trim() + " ";
            }

            holderAddress += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["HOLDER_NAME"].ToString().Trim();
            holderAddress += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_1"].ToString().Trim())
                ? "\n" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_1"].ToString().Trim()
                : string.Empty;
            holderAddress += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_2"].ToString().Trim())
                ? ",\n" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_2"].ToString().Trim()
                : string.Empty;
            holderAddress += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_3"].ToString().Trim())
                ? ",\n" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_3"].ToString().Trim() + ",\n"
                : string.Empty;
            holderAddress += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_4"].ToString().Trim())
                ? ",\n" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTAL_ADD_4"].ToString().Trim()
                : string.Empty;
            holderAddress += ",\n" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["POSTCODE"].ToString().Trim() + " " +
                             ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TOWN_DESC"].ToString().Trim() + "\n" +
                             ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["REGION_NAME"].ToString().Trim();


            document.Add(new Paragraph(holderAddress, bodyFont));
            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            // Add subject
            document.Add(new Paragraph(letterSubject, titleFont));
            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            // Add Letter Content
            document.Add(new Paragraph(GetEmailContent(emailContent), bodyFont));
            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            // Add ending message. Error on below line.
            GetDisclaimer();

            // Finally, add an image in the upper right corner
            var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/logo.jpg"));
            logo.SetAbsolutePosition(440, 800);
            document.Add(logo);

        }

        document.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            string.Format("attachment;filename=Receipt-{0}.pdf",
                DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "")));
        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");

    }
}

private string GetEmailContent(string emailContentId)
{
    DataSet dsEmailBody = new TPD().GetTPDContent(Pms, Convert.ToInt32(emailContentId));
    if (dsEmailBody != null && dsEmailBody.Tables.Count > 0 && dsEmailBody.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return dsEmailBody.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TPD_DESC"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

private void GetDisclaimer()
{
    try
    {
        int tpd_id = 3;

        DataSet ds = new TPD().GetTPDContent(Pms, tpd_id);
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string disclaimer = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TPD_DESC"].ToString()))
            {
                disclaimer = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TPD_DESC"].ToString().Trim();
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(disclaimer);

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(document);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                //pdfDoc.Open();

                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                //pdfDoc.Close();

                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't use `HTMLWorker`, it's nearly two decades old and horrible in more than a few ways >.>. Use `XMLWorker` instead. As for a solution, convert to elements, and add those elements to the document before you close it.

Comment: or use iText 7 + the pdfHTML add-on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTextSharp: "The document is not open" error - when it actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672700/itextsharp-the-document-is-not-open-error-when-it-actually-is)

Comment: The problem is: you're creating a new writter in `GetDisclaimer()` with this call to `GetInstance()`, for that reason document needs to be open **again**. This question is a "possible" duplicate. :)

Comment: Consider passing your writter as an argument to method `GetDisclaimer()`, so that you don't need to make a new one.